# How to append key - values in json object using java

Tags: java, json

I am using org.json.JSONObject package to create a JSONArray by filling up values from db, I can get the values from db and put them a key - pair in json, but at the end of the program: key and values are not appended whereas only the last row of array is converted into json object. I want them to be appended in the final json. Any help will be appreciated.

```
  try {
    MobileTestClass_Methods.InitializeConfiguration();
    String sqlQuery = "SELECT id, NAME FROM campaign LIMIT 4; ";
    Connection con = MobileTestClass_Methods.CreateSQLConnection();

    String [][] arr = MobileTestClass_Methods
        .ExecuteMySQLQueryReturnsArrayWithColumnName(con, sqlQuery);
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
    int totalrow =arr.length;
    int totalcolumn =arr[0].length;

    System.out.println("row: "+totalrow + " col: "+totalcolumn);

    for(int i=1; i<totalrow; i++) {
        for(int j=0; j<totalcolumn; j++) {
            String key = arr[0][j];
            String value = arr[i][j];
            json.put(key, value);
            System.out.println("Key: "+key + "  value: "+value);
        }
    }

    System.out.println("Json: "+json);

    JSONArray array = new JSONArray();
    array.put(json);

    JSONObject main = new JSONObject();
    main.put("result", array);

    System.out.println("Final Json Array: "+main);
  } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
  }
```

**Output:**

```
  row: 5 col: 2
  Key: id  value: 25256
  Key: NAME  value: megha_video
  Key: id  value: 32168
  Key: NAME  value: Mukesh_13Aug_vpaid
  Key: id  value: 25258
  Key: NAME  value: vast
  Key: id  value: 32167
  Key: NAME  value: SDK-rtb-hudson-130815
  Json: {"id":"32167","NAME":"SDK-rtb-hudson-130815"}
  Final Json Array: {"result":[{"id":"32167","NAME":"SDK-rtb-hudson-130815"}]}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The result of your query returns always the keys `id` and `NAME`, so you're overwriting the values continuously.

If you want to have multiple objects with `id` and `NAME` properties you should use a `JSONArray` and create nested `JSONObject`s inside:

```
// ... previous code

String [][] arr = MobileTestClass_Methods.ExecuteMySQLQueryReturnsArrayWithColumnName(con, sqlQuery);
JSONArray json = new JSONArray ();
int totalrow =arr.length;
int totalcolumn =arr[0].length;

System.out.println("row: "+totalrow + " col: "+totalcolumn);

for(int i=1; i<totalrow; i++)
{
    JSONObject row = new JSONObject();
    for(int j=0; j<totalcolumn; j++)
    {
        String key = arr[0][j];
        String value = arr[i][j];
        row.put(key, value);
        System.out.println("Key: "+key + "  value: "+value);
    }
    json.put(row);
}

// ... rest of the code ...
```

Comment: Well I got idea how to fix that, thanks for that. json.put(row) needs to be changed as json object can't contains another json object so I created a json array to have row json object.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I needed to create a json array before starting the loop and then store the json object in the first loop and finally add this json object to json array.

```
String [][] arr = MobileTestClass_Methods.ExecuteMySQLQueryReturnsArrayWithColumnName(con, sqlQuery);
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
            int totalrow =arr.length;
            int totalcolumn =arr[0].length;

            System.out.println("row: "+totalrow + " col: "+totalcolumn);

            JSONArray array = new JSONArray();

            for(int i=1; i<totalrow; i++)
            {
                JSONObject row = new JSONObject();

                for(int j=0; j<totalcolumn; j++)
                {
                    String key = arr[0][j];
                    String value = arr[i][j];
                    row.put(key, value);
                    System.out.println("Key: "+key + "  value: "+value);
                }
                array.put(row);
            }
```